# Why are my .NET CheckListBox Items not selected?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, checklistbox

I have a web application I am programming that builds a SQL query based on user input.  I am currently using a few check boxes without problems.  However, instead of hard-coding the check boxes, I dynamically populated them on `Page_Load` with the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //init();
    sql.Open();

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [value] FROM [table]", sql);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
            chkLst.Items.Add(rdr[0].ToString());
        rdr.Close();
    }
    sql.Close();
}
```

Populating works perfectly.  However, when I try to retrieve `chkLst.Items.Selected` property, it's always set to false, and thus renders the list useless for filtering.  Below is the relevant segment of my code that executes on submit:

```
foreach (ListItem li in chkLst.Items)
    if (li.Selected)
        cmd += li.Text;
```

Since the Selected property is always false, my command always comes up empty.  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: [`CheckedListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox(v=vs.80).aspx) is a winforms control, isn't it? You're showing ASP.NET code (IsPostBack etc.).

Comment: Are you expecting items to be selected (ie have you selected them during the test case)? I'm sure you can set the property programmatically if you want them to appear as selected, but of course that's not going to be the default behavior.

Comment: Is `chkLst` part of your application even?  I see that earlier in the code you are clearing 'chkLstUALFeature` and `chkLstUALFunction` and then not referencing them again.

Comment: I apologize, Brian, I left in some irrelevant code with the other two chkLsts.  I have three of them being used, and forgot to take out those two lines (as they aren't relevant to this issue).

Comment: _"Below is the relevant segment of my code that executes on submit"_ I would suggest to post also the rest anyway. Somewhere in this event handler is your problem.

Comment: Your foreach loop is fine (that's what I've used on a particular page). We're going to need to see more code to see what else might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Someone else had answered my question, but it looks like his answer was deleted, either by him or SO's read-only period today.

The solution was to populate my list in Page_Init instead of Page_Load.

Thanks to the now anonymous respondent!